# Removing brackets and quotes from print in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, readfile, text-parsing

I am trying to remove the brackets from the print statement using Python 2.7 I tried suggestions from various forums but it didn't work as expected finally thought of asking out here myself.

Code:

```
    with open('buttonpress_and_commandstarted','r') as buttonpress_commandstarted:
        for line in buttonpress_commandstarted:
            button_press_command_time = ''
            if os.path.getsize('buttonpress_and_commandstarted') > 0:               
                button_press_command_time = line.split()[2]
            else:
                print "   > Cannot get time stamp as the file is empty"
            button_press = re.findall(r"\:12\:(.*?)\.",line)
            command_executed = re.findall(r"\:4\:(.*?) started\.",line)
            with open('timestamp_buttons_and_commands', 'w') as timestamp_buttons_and_commands:
                timestamp_buttons_and_commands.write(str(button_press_command_time) + str(button_press) + str(command_executed))

            with open("timestamp_buttons_and_commands", "r+") as timestamp_buttons_and_commands:
                contents = timestamp_buttons_and_commands.readlines()
                from string import join 
                result = ''.join(contents)
            print result
```

I am not sure what mistake I am doing.I get the following output

```
00:22:12['Button 9 pressed'][]
00:22:13['Button 9 pressed'][]
00:22:14['Button 9 pressed'][]
00:22:15['Button 9 pressed'][]
00:22:15[]['Command MediaCodec (2)']
00:22:17['Button 9 pressed'][]
00:22:19['Button 9 pressed'][]
00:22:19[]['Command SetSensorFormat (3)']
00:22:22[]['CDC']
00:22:22[]['Command Hello']
00:22:22[]['Command Hello']
00:22:22[]['Command Hello']
00:22:22[]['Command Hello']
00:22:22[]['Command Hello']
00:22:25['Button 10 pressed'][]
```

But I don't want the brackets and quotes

Comment: General tip: dont import modules in the middle of your code

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is - could you cut the code down to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide inputs and expected and actual outputs?

Comment: Also, I think your use of ``join`` is wrong. You import ``join`` from ``string`` and never use it, but instead use the built-in one, which is the same. Hence that import is pointless.

Comment: OK thank you @go2 I will delete it then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.findall` returns a list. When you do `str(someList)`, it will print the brackets and commas:

```
>>> l = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> print str(l)
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

If you want to print without `[` and `,`, use `join`:

```
>>> print ' '.join(l)
a b c
```

If you want to print without `[` but with `,`:

```
>>> print ', '.join(l)
a, b, c
```

And if you want to keep the `'`, you could use `repr` and list comprehension:

```
>>> print ', '.join(repr(i) for i in l)
'a', 'b', 'c'
```

---

After your edit, it seems that there is only 1 element in your lists. So you can only print the first element:

```
>>> l = ['a']
>>> print l
['a']
>>> print l[0]
a
```

Comment: Adding these lines`button_press = ''.join(button_press)
command_executed = ''.join(command_executed)
timestamp_buttons_and_commands.write(str(button_press_command_time) + " : " + str(button_press) + str(command_executed))` did the trick ! Thank you so much :)